# Graph is loading slow and second one is load later

Tags: javascript, json, graph

I am working on a dashboard with a lot of graphs. Every graph get there data from a online `json` file but it loads slow. The second graph wants to load when the first one is fully loaded.

[image: DevTools Network status]

I am using this to get the `json` from the online server.

```
function getData() { 
   $.getJSON("LINK", function(results) {}
} getData();
```

Every graph has his own `javascript` file.

Comment: It looks like maybe the server will only accept one simultaneous call to the "dashboard" URL from a particular client